# Como obtener el valor de unos combos en mi Controller?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, bootstrap, spring

Tengo tres combos, los cuales al cargar la pagina los combos 2 y 3 están inhabilitados, hasta que seleccionas una opción del combo 1 se activa el 2, y al escoger del combo 2, se activa el 3.

Lo que quiero es recuperar el valor de la opción que se haya escogido y ya lo hace, pero quiero mandar ese valor a  mi Controlador, pero sin hacer click en algún  botón, simplemente al seleccionar la opción, como le puedo hacer?

Tengo este método en mi controller el cual me redirecciona a la pagina donde tengo los combos, hice la clase `ObtieneInfoForm` con los atributos para recuperar los id de los combos

```html
@RequestMaping(value="/vista/formularioCombos", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String muestraPantalla(Locale locale, Model model){
 model.addAttribute("datosForm", new ObtieneInfoForm());
 return "formularioCombos";
}
```

y este es mi código en el jsp

```html
<script>
function inhabilitaSelect(){
 
 document.getElementById("#combo2").disabled=true;
 document.getElementById("#combo3").disabled=true;
 
 
 $("#combo1").change(function(){
  
  var valor = $("#combo1").val();
  if(valor >="1"){
   $("#combo2").attr('disabled', false);
  }
  
 });
 
 $("#combo2").change(function(){
  
  var valor = $("#combo2").val();
  if(valor >="1"){
   $("#combo3").attr('disabled', false);
  }
  
 });
 
}
</script>
<form:form method="POST"  modelAttribute="datosForm">
 <select class="form-control" id="combo1" name="combo1">
  <option value="0" selected>Elije una opcion</option>
  <option value="1">Ejemplo1</option>
  <option value="2">Ejemplo2</option>
 </select>
 
 <select class="form-control" id="combo2" name="combo2">
  <option value="0" selected>Elije una opcion</option>
  <option value="1">Ejemplo1</option>
  <option value="2">Ejemplo2</option>
 </select>
 
 <select class="form-control" id="combo3" name="combo3">
  <option value="0" selected>Elije una opcion</option>
  <option value="1">Ejemplo1</option>
  <option value="2">Ejemplo2</option>
 </select>
</form:form>
```

Lo que no se es como puedo hacer eso, obtener el valor de los id en mi controlador?,

Es que los combos serán dependientes al ser llenados con catalogos, es decir, al seleccionar una opción del combo 1, el combo 2 mostrara solamente las opciones correspondientes a lo que se haya escogido en el combo 1, entonces por eso quiero recuperar el id del primer combo para pasarlo como parámetro al query y mostrar en el combo 2, esa lista ya filtrada y lo mismo para el combo 3

Comment: Las llamadas para tratar los eventos en los que se cambia de valor en los combos las tienes metidas dentro de la función inhabilitaSelect, que no sé si la estás llamando en algún sitio. Si no la estás llamando, nunca vas a poder capturar los cambios en los combos. Otra cosa es el problema de enviar al servidor el valor de un combo cuando cambie, que tendrás que hacer por ajax, jsp solo sirve para renderizar la página en el servidor. Si necesitas comportamiento dinámico tienes que usar javascript con alguna librería o jsf, que internamente usa javascript, pero es parecido a jsp en el html

Comment: En otras palabras: en principio tendrías que quitar el evento `change` de adentro de la función, porque no está escuchando realmente el evento, esta encerrado ahí excepto que ejecutes la función.

Comment: Esa función la mando a llamar  desde otra que Inicializa, sólo que olvide ponerla, y si recupera el valor de la opción del combo, sólo que no se como pasar ese valor a mi controlador, gracias